# Filter parts of list

Tags: list, haskell, match

Here is my problem: I have a list like this:

```
[Int]
```

And another list of lists like this:

```
[[([Int], Int)]]
```

Say that list 'a' looks like

```
[2,3,7,4]
```

and list 'b' looks like

```
[([2,3,7,2],1), ([2,3,7,8],3), ([2,3], 2)]
```

I want to first find out if there is a list which starts with `2,3,7,4`, but can have more elements. Then I want to match with lists starting with `2,3,7` and so on. I want to continue until I get matches. Note that I just want to match the first element in the tuple in list 'b' and ignore the second element of the tuple.

I tried using `filter` couldn't get it to work if I wan't to compare just the beginning of the list.

Comment: None of the lists in your second example have type `[[(Int, Int)]]`. The first one doesn't even parse.

Comment: `b` can't contains that tuple, probably, you want something like `[([Int], Int)]`

Comment: Sorry guys, edited out errors. Should be correct now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Into `ghci`

```
:m + Data.List

let a = [2, 3, 7, 4]
let b = [([2, 5, 7, 4, 5], 3),([2, 3, 7, 4, 5], 5),([1, 3, 7, 4], 7)]

filter (\(xs, _) -> a `isPrefixOf` xs) b
```

if no elements match and you wish look for `[2, 3, 7]` (deleting last element and so on) then

```
let f xs a = filter (\(xs, _) -> a `isPrefixOf` xs) b ++ f xs (take (length a - 1) a)
```

then

```
head $ f b [1, 3, 7, 4, 5]
```

(obiously you must to check bad cases like "not found", try yourself!  ;)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use `isPrefixOf`:

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:isPrefixOf